# Sharepoint 2013 License trial to licensed version

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

I have the license for Sharepoint 2013 Enterprise SP1 but the thing is that I have installed the `trial version` but when I try to feed the Enterprise license key it gives this error **This license cannot be used to convert Trial to Enterprise**.

Is there any other way to use the enterprise version? Since this is production environment, I cannot uninstall the Sharepoint itself to install the licensed version. Any other way?

Comment: Not a positive link but: http://blog.kuppens-switsers.net/it/sharepoint-2013-trial-license-license-upgrade-fail/

Comment: R u sure it is enterprise key? Steps are same which u performed to convert it.you need ent license key to convert it